Why can't my PowerShell script detect the property of my CSV header?
I am trying to the the below script to write to a CSV file with 3 headers but keep getting the following error 'The property 'exit' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.'



VRN
Entry
Exit




Test
09/04/2024 12:49
test


testi
09/04/2024 13:02




CSV file
$csvFilePath = "\\VRN.csv"

# Prompt user for input
$VRN = Read-Host "Enter VRN:"
$EntryTime = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

# Load existing CSV data
$existingData = Import-Csv $csvFilePath

# Check if a record with the same VRN exists
$existingRecord = $existingData | Where-Object { $_.VRN -eq $VRN }

if ($existingRecord) {
    # Record with VRN already exists
    if ($existingRecord.Exit -eq "") {
        # Update Exit time if Exit column is empty
        $existingRecord.Exit = $EntryTime
    } else {
        # Create a new row with the same VRN
        $newRow = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            VRN = $VRN
            Entry = $EntryTime
            Exit = ""
        }
        $existingData += $newRow
    }
} else {
    # Create a new row for the VRN
    $newRow = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        VRN = $VRN
        Entry = $EntryTime
        Exit = ""
    }
    $existingData += $newRow
}

# Save updated data back to CSV
$existingData | Export-Csv $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "CSV file updated successfully!"

I want the script to write the input to the VRN column with the date/time in the entry column. If there is already a entry time, the date/time to add to the Exit column.
I got to work but then it over writ an existing exit time which lead me to the script I've got now but getting the above error? please help

Can you show the first few lines of your csv file? Anonymise the data if needed, but keep the header row as id. And post it by updating your original question post please, not as a comment...

As a CSV is text, cutpaste the content (including the header line), don't just give us a picture.

exit is a PowerShell keyword. help about_Language_Keywords It may work as a variable or member name, but it is not advisable.

Look at your if/else statements.  #newRow has to be in each branch of the if/else.

$csvFilePath = '\\VRN.csv'

$EntryTime = Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'

# Prompt user for input
$VRN = Read-Host 'Enter VRN:'


# Load existing CSV data in a collection
[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$existingData = Import-Csv .\zio.csv

# Check if a record with the same VRN exists
$existingRecord = $existingData | Where-Object { $_.VRN -eq $VRN }


if ($existingRecord) {
    #if Entry is empty, populate it with the time
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($existingRecord.Entry)) {
        $existingData[$existingData.IndexOf($existingRecord)].Entry = $EntryTime
    }
    # if Entry si not empty but Exit is, populate exit
    elseif ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($existingRecord.Exit)) {
        $existingData[$existingData.IndexOf($existingRecord)].Exit = $EntryTime
    }
}
# if there is no ierm with that name, crate one and append it 
else {
    $existingData.Add([pscustomobject]@{ VRn = $VRN; Entry = $EntryTime; Exit = $null })
}


# export the modified collection to CSV
$existingData | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

